# VBA Excel assistance in userform refedit control

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have setup my userform perfectly so that when the user enters the date it shows in a label box in the userform it self.

All I'm struggling with is using my output frame as shown, which contains a refEdit control and a button. I am trying to have the date to be placed on any worksheet cell.

Image of my userform:

[image]

So far the code that I have come up with is the following:

```
 Private Sub avgBtn_Click()
    Dim range1 As String
    Dim newdate As String

    range1 = TextBox3.Value + "," + TextBox1.Value + " " + TextBox2.Value + "," + TextBox4.Value


    newdate = range1

   Label7.Caption = newdate

 End Sub

 Private Sub cancelBtn_Click()
     Unload Task2
 End Sub


 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    TextBox4.Value = ""

   End Sub


 Private Sub UserForm_Click()
     Unload UserForm1
 End Sub
```

For the refedit control and command button I have come up with this code but it is giving me errors:

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim myCell As Range

  Set myCell = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set myCell = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value).Areas(1).Cells(1)
  myCell.value = Label7.Caption

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any feedback in regards to this code.

Comment: What is `RefEdit1.Value` when the error is thrown?  Not that the line `Set myCell = Nothing` does exactly nothing - that's the value it is initialized to. The variable `newdate` would also need to be declared in a higher scope.

Comment: @Comintern yes it is the same image

Comment: it will let the user select a cell, however when the user clicks write date to sheet nothing happens, not even an error pops up

Comment: That's because `myCell.value = newdate` is writing an empty `Variant`.  Try `myCell.value = Label7.Caption`.

Comment: Your code works for me.  Although you say the RefEdit control is on the userform you have shown above, I don't see it.  Is it in fact on that form and if so, could you post a picture that includes the control?  If it is located on a different userform then that is probably your issue for the code as written.